# How to debug a Library using Windows Store App

Tags: debugging, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, class-library

Is it posible to debug a Portable Class Library in Visual Studio 2013 using a Windows Store App?

So far, I had to close the current solution containing the library then I had to open another (containging the app) to debug the library. It is quite annoying.

I tried selecting the executable `<Project dir>/bin/Debug/calcualtor.exe` in the project settings `Project->Properties->Debug->Start External Program` but it shows an error *Unable to start program...* while tying to Start Debugging.

Briefly, what I try to avoid is switching solutions over and over. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried attaching the process to it?

Comment: I have not. what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Have you tried adding the PCL to the same project as your app?

Comment: Thanks, @NateDiamond. Now, if I hit F5 it starts as expected.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the PCL to your Windows Store App's solution. You will be able to debug it just the same as your Windows Store App.